# How can I import all emails and tagging from one gmail account into another?

Tags: gmail

It is easy to import the emails using pop etc?

However how do I import:

- All my labels etc
- My contact list

Comment: Moving over labels: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/347/how-can-i-import-mail-from-one-gmail-account-to-another-preserving-my-label-stru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the answers to your other question?

Per [the link](http://knol.google.com/k/changing-your-gmail-username-or-email-address#) I gave in [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3934/how-can-my-wife-explain-to-gmail-that-her-name-changed-when-we-got-married/3942#3942) to [your other question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3934/how-can-my-wife-explain-to-gmail-that-her-name-changed-when-we-got-married):

> If you absolutely need the old label structure, the only solution is to use an IMAP client to connect to both the old and new account and copy over folders/labels. But this solution can be tricky, because you can only copy over a certain (unspecified) amount of mail at a time. The non-Google program Gmail Backup might be able to assist with this process, but I can't vouch for its effectiveness.

Regarding contacts, from the same link:

> Step 3: Export and import your contacts
>   Login to the old account and follow the instructions on the Export Gmail contacts page. Remember the location of the saved file.
>
> Login to the new account and follow the instructions on the Importing CSV files page using the file you just saved.

Comment: sorry the status bar does not update to say I have new answers while I am typing in a quession...  I have a set of long standing quesions on gmail that I am now hoping to find answers to.

Comment: @Lipis, I only tend to accept an answer if it completly solve the problem.  I also tend to wait for a few days if it is not clear that an answer is the best possible answer to a problem.

Comment: @Ian cool... :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a way of importing the labels, but you can easily import all your contacts:

1. Go to your contacts in your old account, press `Export` and save as Google CSV file.
2. Go to your contacts in your new account, press `Import` and choose the exported file.