# How can I save all of my received emails onto my laptop or an external hard drive?

Tags: gmail, export

My work email is being deactivated. My laptop is a Macintosh.

Comment: See also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3938/how-can-i-import-all-emails-and-tagging-from-one-gmail-account-into-another?rq=1

Comment: See also [Export Gmail messages to text or HTML files](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/417)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a third-party email client and get your messages via the POP and/or IMAP protocols. A desktop client is usually assumed, but you might be able to use a webmail app like Outlook.com. (You'll have a lot less control of your data with the latter.)

From [the Data Liberation Front](http://www.dataliberation.org/google/gmail):

> ### Escaping from Gmail
>
> #### IMAP, POP Access
>
> It's easy to use a different email reading program with Gmail using either IMAP or POP, or to get all your mail out to take to a different provider.  Go to the Settings page (link at top right of Gmail page), [Forwarding and POP/IMAP tab](https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/fwdandpop).
>
> This tab lets you set up POP and IMAP, with instructions for popular email reading programs.  There is extensive online help available for both [POP](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/topic.py?topic=12805) and [IMAP](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=12806). And in case you are not familiar with the difference between POP and IMAP, here's a simple chart:
>
> [image]
> <sub>(source: [dataliberation.org](http://www.dataliberation.org/_/rsrc/1252961393807/google/gmail/POPIMAPvs.png))</sub>

Comment: Would IMAP be desirable in this situation? Wouldn't there be a danger of emails being deleted locally if an attempt was later made to sync with the "deactivated" mailbox (or if emails were purged in the live mailbox before deactivation)?!

Comment: @w3d: It depends on what's to be done. If someone is looking to move all of the messages to another email account (say another Gmail account) I would use IMAP. If the desire is simply to download the messages to keep as an archive, I'd use POP.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download all of your emails using an email client such as Mail on the Mac. Instructions on doing so can be found [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/download-gmail-google-data/)